# Render with timber (twig) directly from string

Tags: wordpress, twig, twig-extension

I am trying to combine my wordpress project with Timber. To do it, I need to render twig templates through timber with wordpress `global wp_query`.

So far I found out solution for twig, and it works:

```
$twig = new \Twig_Environment(new \Twig_Loader_String());
return $rendered = $twig->render(
  "<title>{{ site.name }}</title>",
  array('site' => $site)
);
```

However, I have no idea how to do it using Timber. Only way I know is from `.twig` file. I was looking for solution, but found nothing. I need to pass many wordpress variables in order to use them in templates and Timber would do it automatically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking through the source, it looks like [there's a `render_string()` method](https://github.com/jarednova/timber/blob/master/timber.php#L328). It should work mostly same as a regular `render()`.

```
$context = Timber::get_context();
$context['foo'] = 'Bar!';
$context['post'] = new TimberPost();
Timber::render_string('{{ post.id }} - {{ foo }}', $context);
```